# Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner

Tags: android, android-xml, androidx

We are seeing a crash **Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner** on the play console,but we are not able to reproduce it.
Here is my xml :

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerState"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/xMargin_42_156"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/xMargin_42_156"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_down_arrow"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:overlapAnchor="false"/>
```

In build.gradle

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'

Logs:

Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.wrap/com.wrap.activities.NewIntroActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #129 in com.wrap:layout/activity_new_intro: Binary XML file line #129 in com.wrap:layout/activity_new_intro: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner

Comment: Do you have any log?

Comment: @Jameido added logs